# Testing private methods in groovy

Tags: testing, groovy

In Java it is very extended to enforce the use of package-protected instead of private in order to make easier to test methods.

Now i am switching to Groovy and one of the first things i noticed is the public by default access modifier and, later, that package-protected is not very clean and easy to use in Groovy as it was in Java.

Then i also realized about private fields and private methods are not private "bug" --> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1875

... but, of course, this is a bug that may be solved at some moment so i shall not rely on this (Shall i?)

So ... what is the prefered way to test restricted methods in groovy?

Comment: You should assume that defect is not going to be fixed.   :)

Comment: Yeah ... i've seen that opinion out there ... but the fact is that it is still open as an issue, I think i should assume it at the moment that issue is closed in Jira with "Won't fix" ... otherwise there is no guarantee.

Comment: Also ... what is the point of private access selector then?

Comment: why do you even want to test implementation details in the first place?

Comment: That may be a good question and i appreciate that kind of thoughts ... in my understanding i shall test implementation details in unit tests (at least). I may not be interested about implementation details in functional or acceptance testing ... but code shall be tested at some point.

Comment: a private method was written by the author to extract some (common used) code into its own method.  you should not care for this at any stage of testing.  test the contract and the sideeffects, but leave the code under test some leeway to do its job.

Comment: You can make fields/methods of a Groovy class package-protected simply by annotating them with `@PackageScope`. I don't agree that this is "not very clean and easy to use"?

Comment: @cfrick The problem is when method refactoring needs testing, good example I am currently working on is a method with complex argument validation. The code still belongs in the parent function's class as a private method and the parent function benefits with simpler logic `validateArgs(...); doThing()`. The ability to test this code separately is very helpful to me whilst still maintaining encapsulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the question is if Groovy will in the future ignore private visibility too. You can be sure that in Groovy 2.x this won't be fixed. It might get in a future new major version like Groovy 3. But this version will then contain incompatible fixes anyway, plus it is most likely, that there will be still a way to get the old functionality. So for the near future don't expect that to be "fixed"